# onTap doesn't work on ListWheelScrollView children items - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to make a list of items using `ListWheelScrollView` and I want to have the ability of `tapping` on items but it seems `onTap` doesn't work.

Here is a simple code

```
List<int> numbers = [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5
          ];

...


Container(
  height: 200,
  child: ListWheelScrollView(
    controller: fixedExtentScrollController,
    physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
    children: numbers.map((month) {
      return Card(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print(123);
            },
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        month.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                      ),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ));
    }).toList(),
    itemExtent: 60.0,
  ),
)
```

Is there something wrong with this code ? I'm pretty sure something like this will work on a `ListView` or other scrolling widgets.

Comment: This might be an issue, you'll just have to use a different kind of list for now. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38803

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @SimranAswani no, I didn't use this widget in the end, but I think by using the `Listener` widget instead of `GestureDetector`, its possible to detect onTap

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. I hope is helpful.

1. create a int variable in State class.

class _MenuWheelState extends State {
int _vIndiceWheel;

2. in the Function onSelectedItemChanged of the ListWheelScrollView set the variable:

   onSelectedItemChanged: (ValueChanged) {
   setState(() {
   _vIndiceWheel = ValueChanged; });
   },
3. create a GestureDetecture and put the ListWheelScrollView inside:

   GestureDetector(
   child: ListWheelScrollView(...
4. create onTap function at the GestureDetecture like this code:

   // this is necessary
   if (_vIndiceWheel == null) {
   _vIndiceWheel = 0;
   }

   switch (_vIndiceWheel) {
   case 0:
   {
   Navigator.push(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) {
   return YourSecondScreen();
   },
   ...